# "traversal failed: u: Bad message" when deleting an extremely large directory in Linux

Tags: linux, shell, directory, rm

I am trying to remove some extremely large directories, however no success. Here are some observations:

```bsh
# cwd contains the two larger directories
$ ls -lhF
drwxrwxr-x 2 hongxu hongxu 471M Oct 16 18:52 J/
drwxr-xr-x 2 hongxu hongxu 5.8M Oct 16 17:21 u/
# Note that this is the output of `ls` of the directory themselves so they should be *huge*
# J/ seems much larger than u/ (containing more files), so take u/ as an example

$ rm -rf u/
# hang for a very long time, and finally report
rm: traversal failed: u: Bad message

$ cd u/
# can cd into u/ without problems

$ ls -lhF
# hang for a long time; cancel succeeds when I press Ctrl-C

$ rm *
# hang for a long time; cancel fails when I press Ctrl-C
# however there are no process associated with `rm` as reported by `ps aux`
```

These two directories mostly contain lots of small files (each of which not exceeding 10k, I suppose). Now that I have to remove these two directories to free more disk space. What should I do?

**UPDATE1:**
Please see the output of `rm -rf u/` which tells that `rm: traversal failed: u: Bad message` after quite a long time (> 2 hours). Therefore, the problem seems not about efficiency.

**UPDATE2:**
When applying `fsck`, it reports as follows (seems fine):

```bsh
$ sudo fsck -A -y /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/sda1: 13 files, 1884/130812 clusters

$ df /dev/sda2
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      244568380 189896000  43628648  82% /
```

**UPDATE3:**
<s>In case it may be relevant (but probably not), these two directories (`J/` and `u/`) contain `terminfo` generated by `tic` command; different from regular compiled terminfo files (e.g., those inside `/lib/terminfo`), these were generated with some fuzzing techniques so may not be "legal" terminfo files.</s> irrelevant!

**UPDATE4:**
Some more observations:

```bsh
$ find u/ -type f | while read f; do echo $f; rm -f $f; done
# hang for a long time, IUsed (`df -i /dev/sda2`) not decreased
```

```bsh
$ mkdir emptyfolder && rsync -r --delete emptyfolder/ u/
# hang for a long time, IUsed (`df -i /dev/sda2`) not decreased
```

```bsh
$ strace rm -rf u/
execve("/bin/rm", ["rm", "-rf", "u"], 0x7fffffffc550 /* 121 vars */) = 0                                                                                                                       
brk(NULL)                               = 0x555555764000                                                                                                                                       
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                                
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                                
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3                                                                                                                                   
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=125128, ...}) = 0                                                                                                                                      
mmap(NULL, 125128, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7fd8000                                                                                                                              
close(3)                                = 0                                                                                                                                                    
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)                                                                                                                
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3                                                                                                                    
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260\34\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832                                                                                                     
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030544, ...}) = 0                                                                                                                                     
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7fd6000                                                                                                      
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff79e4000                                                                                                     
mprotect(0x7ffff7bcb000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0                                                                                                                                               
mmap(0x7ffff7dcb000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7ffff7dcb000                                                                           
mmap(0x7ffff7dd1000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7ffff7dd1000                                                                                 
close(3)                                = 0                                                                                                                                                    
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7ffff7fd7540) = 0                                                                                                                                                    
mprotect(0x7ffff7dcb000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0                                                                                                                                                 
mprotect(0x555555762000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0                                                                                                                                                  
mprotect(0x7ffff7ffc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0                                                                                                                                                  
munmap(0x7ffff7fd8000, 125128)          = 0                                                                                                                                                    
brk(NULL)                               = 0x555555764000                                                                                                                                       
brk(0x555555785000)                     = 0x555555785000                                                                                                                                       
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3                                                                                                                     
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1683056, ...}) = 0                                                                                                                                     
mmap(NULL, 1683056, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7ffff7e3b000                                                                                                                             
close(3)                                = 0                                                                                                                                                    
ioctl(0, TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0                                                                                                                                      
lstat("/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0                                                                                                                                      
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "u", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6045696, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0                                                                                               
openat(AT_FDCWD, "u", O_RDONLY|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_NOFOLLOW|O_DIRECTORY) = 3                                                                                                                 
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=6045696, ...}) = 0                                                                                                                                     
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x38800 (flags O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_NOFOLLOW|O_DIRECTORY)                                                                               
fcntl(3, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)           = 0                                                                                                                                                    
getdents(3, /* 2 entries */, 32768)     = 48                                                                                                                                                   
getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 24                                                                                                                                                   
... (repeated lines)                                                                                                                                                                           
getdents(3, /* 1 entries */, 32768)     = 24                                                                                                                                                   
getdents(3strace: Process 5307 detached                                                                                                                                                        
 <detached ...>
# (manually killed)
```

```
$ ls -f1 u/
./ 
../
../
../
../
... (repeated lines)
../
```

```bsh
$ sudo journalctl -ex
Oct 17 16:00:16 CSLRF03AU kernel: JBD2: Spotted dirty metadata buffer (dev = sda2, blocknr = 0). There's a risk of filesystem corruption in case of system crash.
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error: 6971 callbacks suppressed
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm find: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm zsh: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm rm: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm find: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm rsync: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm zsh: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm zsh: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm rm: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm find: Directory index failed checksum
Oct 17 16:00:20 CSLRF03AU kernel: EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm find: Directory index failed checksum
# #9789534 is the inode of `u/` as reported by `ls -i`
```

So should be a filesystem corruption.
But rebooting does not work :(

Comment: `rm` or the fts interface it's using is clearly confused; I cannot find how any fs related interface (either in fat or any other disk fs) can fail with EBADMSG = "Bad message". What is your kernel version?

Comment: @mosvy 4.15.0-48-generic

Comment: To me this looks like a bug in `fts(3)` functions of glibc -- it would help if tried debugging it. Try `strace`-ing the `rm`, though it's going to be painfully slow.

Comment: It looks like you ran fsck on a mounted filesystem. Can you reboot and use recovery mode or a live usb or something to fsck the unmounted system, once again?

Comment: @muru yeah, will try a live usb to fsck the root filesystem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved the issues. It was due to the filesystem errors that cause `ls` to display wrongly, and other utilities to malfunction.
I'm sorry that the question title is misleading (despite that there are indeed many files inside `u/`, the directory is *not extremely large*).

I solved the problem by using a live usb since the corrupted filesystem is `/`. The fix was simply applying `sudo fsck -cfk /dev/sda2` where `dev/sda2` is the corrupted disk.

Answer (score 6):

You can't remove huge quantities of files using `rm`. You can either do

```
find u/ -type f -print0 | xargs -r -0 rm -f
```

this will delete only files; to delete everything, use

```
find u/ -print0 | xargs -r -0 rm -rf
```

you can probably use the `--delete` option of `find`, if your system has it:

```
find u/ -type f --delete
```

or the funky method with `rsync`:

```
mkdir emptyfolder
rsync -r --delete emptyfolder/ u/
```

`rsync` is way faster than `rm` when deleting things as it will bypass some checks.

Comment: Thanks! I tried `find u/ -type f > files_list.dat` for ~5min, but `files_list.dat` is still 0 bytes; so may be not working. `rsync` approach is also in progress (lasted ~10min). The whole disk size seems decreasing (rather slowly, several bytes per second). Will keep updating results.

Comment: `files_list.dat` still 0 bytes, not working. disk size no major differences. Perhaps I should reboot this machine to see whether problem still exists...

Comment: what do you get when you run "df -i" ? this will give you the number of inodes used (file count) for each disks. To give you an idea, I had to delete a few millions of files many times and it always takes long time... up to hours... if you run periodically df -i during your delete process and see the inode count decreasing, it means it's working

Comment: `IUsed` remains unchanged, so I guess nothing actually works... Maybe I should indeed reboot the server later...

Comment: any error messages in syslog/dmesg ?

Comment: Indeed! it tells `EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_htree_next_block:948: inode #9789534: block 1020: comm find: Directory index failed checksum`

Comment: So should be a file system corruption...

Comment: try a e2fsck -f /dev/sda

Obviously, umount the partition first

Comment: `rm -rf $DIR` should not care about the number of files in $DIR. OP's problem was a fs corruption.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `find /u -type f | while read f; do rm -f $f; done`
This will take a while but might work. For some reason, loops in bash works well when other approaches fails.

Comment: tried `find u -type f | while read f; do echo $f; rm -f $f; done`, however it does not echo anything, so I guess still failed...

Comment: `find u -type f` also does not output anything (hangs there).

Comment: This is very strange. cd u/ and then ls prints the files?

Comment: It *hang for a long time; cancel succeeds when I press Ctrl-C*. See the observations in question description.

Comment: OK. Try to run `find u/ -type f > files_list.dat` . Wait until it finish, in case of millions of files it may take a while...  Then run something like `cat files_list.dat | while read f; do echo $f; rm -f $f; done`